# Others in Macintosh HD

Tags: memory, storage

How can I reduce the size of my HD folder? I have more than 22 GB in "others". 
It is actually using more memory than my documents and apps and does not show contents.
I have deleted the main info in mobileSync folder, but is still very big.

Comment: Where are you seeing this. On the Mac there is no HD folder

Comment: A hard disk volume may be called "HD", and represented in the Finder in the same way as a folder is represented.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of [Daisy Disk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com). It gives you a graphical display of the usage of your drive. It lets you delete items pretty quickly too. You can try it for free. (Disclaimer: not associated with Daisy Disk except as a satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 0):

- open your HD in the Finder and press Command-2
- then open view options (Command-J) and select **calculate all sizes**
- you can find folders with large use and expand them, focusing your attention on /Users first and clean up things that are larger than you care to have around