# Free up over 70 GB of Applications

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

Today I checked out my MacBook Air's storage and found that my Mac is using 70.53 GB on applications out of 120.47 GB. I can't figure out where it is being used as I didn't download any applications. How can free up my Mac's storage?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/others-in-macintosh-HD to see how to sort items by size in a folder.

Answer (score 3):

To see the size of each application

- open the `/Applications` folder in Finder
- switch to list view
- make sure to have 'Size' selected in the options (<kbd>Cmd-J</kbd>)

and wait a few minutes until all folder sizes are calculated by the system. Then sort by Size and remove any big apps you don't need any longer. I wouldn't recommend to delete the standard applications though.

Comment: I checked the size of all my applications it's around 10 GB... Why is it showing 70 GB O_o

Comment: I’d also add checking the `/Library` folders—very carefully. The last thing you want to do is delete something that will muck things up.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use this free and opensource utility: [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/)

It will show you graphically the disk usage. For each rectangle there is also the option "Reveal in Finder" (right click menu) to open directly the selected file/folder.

Comment: And GrandPerspective was previously known as [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com)

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com). It provides a nice graphical view of the different types of data on your disk. It also permits you to drill down into each data type to get details, as well as delete files from within the application.

Here's a sample of how it looks:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You have applications in places other than the Applications folder. To see them all run the system information app (About this Mac > More Info... > System Report...and select Applications under Software in the left panel